# How to properly url encode a string

Tags: php, html, decode, encode

I'm trying to parse a file name to a `url` string.

the file name is:

```
201-SALÃO DE JOGOS.jpg
```

I need the output be exactly this:

```
201-SAL%c3O%20DE%20JOGOS.jpg
```

I'm trying like this:

```
$var = 201-SALÃO DE JOGOS.jpg;
echo urlencode($var);
```

But instead it returns:

```
201-SAL%C3%83O+DE+JOGOS.jpg
```

This is not a valid url. I've already tried with `htmlspecialchars()` and `htmlentities()` but these do not work.

Comment: "and this is not a valid url." sure it is. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: I need the empty spaces be like `%20` not `+`. That's the only problem

Comment: Could I understand why do you want `%20` not `+`? @IvanMoreira

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [**`rawurlencode`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php)

```
$filename = "201-SALÃO DE JOGOS.jpg";
print rawurlencode($filename);
```

Comment: `mb_rawurlencode` is nonsense; `rawurlencode` works on a byte level and doesn't care about the encoding at all. In fact, the results of both functions are identical. I have no idea why that commenter thought an mb variant would be useful in any way.

Comment: @deceze: Ok. Thanks for the updates. Removed the comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot! my code now is `$var = '201-SALÃO DE JOGOS.jpg';
echo rawurlencode(utf8_decode($var));`

Comment: @IvanMoreira: Why you have used `utf8_decode` when `rawurlencode` is already giving you exactly want you want?

Comment: `rawurlencode` is not giving me exactly what i want( i don't know why). To make the string be exactly the way i want, i had to use `utf8_decode`

Comment: @Ivan I see. You actually want your string to be ISO-8859-1 encoded. Maybe you should fix that at the source, since right now you appear to be using UTF-8 encoded strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could able to use `str_replace` to replace `+` with `%20`:

```
<?php

$var = "201-SALÃO DE JOGOS.jpg";
$output = str_replace('+','%20',urlencode($var));
echo $output;
echo "*****";
echo urldecode($output);
?>
```